# Why won't my batch files run since I changed a Windows "Environment Variable"?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, environment-variables, kernow

I had a couple of batch files to help me with minor tasks (one killed a running Skype process and the other deleted a file before running an executable). Both were only one or two lines of simple code.

To run a program called Kernow I was told I needed to add a Windows environment variable called "Path" and set it to point to a Java folder (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin*) - the program wouldn't run until I had done this giving a Java error.

I already had an environment variable called path which pointed to a long file path so instead of adding a variable I simply updated that one.

Now neither of the batch files that were working fine before will work. Both will run with no errors but not produce results.

I have very little knowledge of how batch files work with Windows. Can I set another environment variable called Path that will enable me to run my batch files *and* run Kernow??

Comment: Post your entire path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably messed up with adding the folder to your path.

Your path should look like this:

> C:\Folder1;C:\Folder2

When you add Java, you need to append it and add a semicolon, like this:

> C:\Folder1;C:\Folder2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

You may have missed the semicolon or completely overwritten the path.

An easy command to do this, as mentioned by @unclemeat in the comments:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you'll want to do something like `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`.

Comment: Ahhh that solves it thank you. Yes I was missing other values from the path - I didn't realise it could be multiple _paths_. I've found them and put them back and now it all works a treat.